# Ignoring \n in regex even if its tied to the word you are looking for

Tags: regex

Let's say I have this text:

```
"""xsdsdsds\ncat xsdhidhf"""
```

and my regex is:

```
val myRegex = "\b(?i)cat\b"
```

This doesn't recognize that the text above has the word `cat` in it because its tied to the `\n` character.

How can I change the regex to find a word as a whole (with spaces from both sides) but ignore the `\n`?

Comment: You mean you want `val myRegex = """(?i)(?<=\b|\\n)cat\b"""`?

Comment: Is it Kotlin or Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```scala
val myRegex = """(?i)(?<=\b|\\n)cat\b"""
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `(?<=\b|\\n)` - either a word boundary or a `\n` text must appear immediately on the left
- `cat` - a string `cat`
- `\b`  - a word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QB9PFw/1).

Comment: how do I change this query to say NOT? like that same word is not in the string

Comment: @JohnBigs `val myRegex = """(?i)^(?!.*(?<=\b|\\n)cat\b).*"""`